# MTURK API: Accessing Private Field of Assignment Object from PHP?

Tags: php, aws-sdk, mechanicalturk

My PHP app is accessing MTURK via the API and getting an `Assignment` object back that looks like this:

[image: Assignment Object]

I'm trying to access the `Answer` field. So far I've tried:

```
$temp = $theResult->Answer;
$temp = $theResult->get('Answer');
```

...but they throw errors.

What is the correct way to access this field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works on my installation:

```
$answers = $theResult->getAnswer();
```